# Create a function that replaces varchar by dictionary table?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to build a function where I would be able to do something like this:

`replace_with_dict(<this_table_to_replace_column, <dictionary_table>, <dictionary_from_field>, <dictionary_to_field>)`

The dictionary table would have a from and to column, and the function would replace all occurrences of any of the dictionary from field into its to field.

I was trying by myself, but not getting success.
Here what I did until now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_with_dict( to_replace VARCHAR, 
dict_table regclass, from_field VARCHAR, to_field VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
    DECLARE
        replaced VARCHAR;
        dict_entry RECORD;
        from_replace_pattern VARCHAR;
        to_replace_pattern VARCHAR;
        dictionary CURSOR FOR SELECT from_field AS "in", to_field AS "out" FROM basf_dict;
    BEGIN 
        replaced := to_replace;
--      EXECUTE(format('SELECT %S, %S FROM %S;', from_field, to_field, dict_table)) IN dictionary;
        FOR dic_entry IN dictionary LOOP
            from_replace_pattern := ' ' || dic_entry."in"  || ' ';
            to_replace_pattern   := ' ' || dic_entry."out" || ' ';
            replaced := REPLACE(replaced, from_replace_pattern, to_replace_pattern);
        END LOOP;
        RETURN replaced;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

When I try to run the above function in a query like this, `replace_with_dict(p.nom_produto, "basf_dict", "de", "para"),`. I'm getting this error:

```
  SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "basf_dict" does not exist
  Posição: 86
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "basf_dict" does not exist
  Posição: 86
```

**EDIT 1:**

Just notice that for variable was misspelled. I've fixed it, now my function declaration looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_with_dict( to_replace VARCHAR, dict_table VARCHAR, from_field VARCHAR, to_field VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
    DECLARE
        replaced VARCHAR;
        dict_entry RECORD;
        from_replace_pattern VARCHAR;
        to_replace_pattern VARCHAR;
--      dictionary CURSOR FOR SELECT from_field AS d_in, to_field AS d_out FROM basf_dict;
        query text;
    BEGIN 
        query := format('SELECT %I, %I FROM %I;', from_field, to_field, dict_table);
        replaced := to_replace;

        FOR dict_entry IN EXECUTE query LOOP
            from_replace_pattern := ' ' || dic_entry.d_in  || ' ';
            to_replace_pattern   := ' ' || dic_entry.d_out || ' ';
            replaced := REPLACE(replaced, from_replace_pattern, to_replace_pattern);
        END LOOP;
        RETURN replaced;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

still not working, now I'm getting the follow error when trying to run the query that uses this function:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dic_entry"
  Onde: PL/pgSQL function replace_with_dict(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 14 at assignment
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dic_entry"
  Onde: PL/pgSQL function replace_with_dict(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 14 at assignment
```

**EDIT 2:**

For better explaining my motivation for creating the function, here is what I'm trying to not do:

```
SELECT
        p.id,
        p.nom_produto,
        string_ranking_by_array( 
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    p.nom_produto,
                    'FOS',
                    'FO'),
                'S B', 
                'S_B'), 
            string_to_array( pe.nom_produto, ' ' ) 
        ) AS ranking,
        pe.nom_produto AS nom_pe,
        pe.ean_produto,
        pe.id AS id_pe
    FROM
        produto p, produto_empresa pe
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND p.id_loja = 23
        AND( p.ean_produto IS NULL OR p.ean_produto = '' )
        AND CHAR_LENGTH( cod_produto )= 12
        AND cod_produto LIKE 'SC%'
    ORDER BY
        ranking DESC,
        p.nom_produto
```

I don't want to make more inner replaces for every new improvement that I may find.

Comment: First: string constants need single quotes, not double quotes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS and secondly: you can't use a variable as a table name like that. You need dynamic SQL to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your function:

- the name of the loop variable is `dict_entry` while you are trying to use `dic_entry`;
- the columns `d_in` and `d_out` are unknown unless you define them in the query as aliases.

Besides, you should select from the dictionary table only rows matching separate words of input string to reduce number of loops. Use also `regexp_replace()` instead of `replace()` to replace only whole words (your attempt with spaces will not work properly). The escapes `\m` and `\M` mean the beginning and the end of a word, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_with_dict
    (to_replace VARCHAR, dict_table VARCHAR, from_field VARCHAR, to_field VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
    DECLARE
        dict_entry RECORD;
        query text;
        pattern text;
        words text[];
    BEGIN 
        words := string_to_array(to_replace, ' ');
        query := format(
            'SELECT %I AS d_in, %I AS d_out FROM %I WHERE %I = ANY(%L);',
            from_field, to_field, dict_table, from_field, words
            );
        FOR dict_entry IN EXECUTE query LOOP
            pattern := format('\m%s\M', dict_entry.d_in);
            to_replace := regexp_replace(to_replace, pattern, dict_entry.d_out, 'g');
        END LOOP;
        RETURN to_replace;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[See this working example.](http://rextester.com/BDML19304)

If you do not care about whole words and want to replace any substring (maybe with spaces inside), use simple `replace()` without additional spaces:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_with_dict_simple
    (to_replace VARCHAR, dict_table VARCHAR, from_field VARCHAR, to_field VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
    DECLARE
        dict_entry RECORD;
        query text;
    BEGIN 
        query := format(
            'SELECT %I AS d_in, %I AS d_out FROM %I;',
            from_field, to_field, dict_table, from_field
            );
        FOR dict_entry IN EXECUTE query LOOP
            to_replace := replace(to_replace, dict_entry.d_in, dict_entry.d_out);
        END LOOP;
        RETURN to_replace;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I got some cases where it did worked as it supposed to. http://rextester.com/AEE28978 I believe  it has something with words with spaces. Could you help me to improve it?

Comment: Yes, the first function (which splits an input string into words) does not work properly in your example. When there are spaces in searched words then the second option (`replace_with_dict_simple()`) is suitable, as it's mentioned in the answer. [See this test](http://rextester.com/TCFWB56806).

Comment: Thank you very much. I miss typed when testing the second one. Thank you very very much. It will make my query so easier.

Answer (score 0):

smth like this:

```
t=# create table so6(d_from text,d_to text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so6 select 'street', 'calle';
INSERT 0 1
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_with_dict( to_replace VARCHAR, dict_table regclass, from_field VARCHAR, to_field VARCHAR)
t-# RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
t$#     DECLARE
t$#         _r text;
t$#         _l record;
t$#     BEGIN
t$#       _r = to_replace;
t$#       for _l in (select unnest(string_to_array(to_replace, ' ')) w) loop
t$#         execute (format('SELECT coalesce(replace($s$%s$s$,%I,%I),$s$%s$s$) FROM %I WHERE %I = $v$%s$v$;', to_replace,from_field, to_field, _r,dict_table, from_field,_l.w)) into _r;
t$#         if _r is not null then
t$#           to_replace = _r;
t$#         end if;
t$#       end loop;
t$#       return to_replace;
t$#     END;
t$# $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
t-# ;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 7.404 ms
t=# select replace_with_dict('go to street "LA Palma"','so6'::regclass,'d_from','d_to')
t-# ;
   replace_with_dict
------------------------
 go to calle "LA Palma"
(1 row)

Time: 0.938 ms
```

But I think you should think if you really want to do such thing

Comment: In my case I'm trying to do something where you would pass `replace_with_dict('test street', so6::regclass, d_from, d_to)` (using your `so6` as example) what would result in a `test calle` output. Wasn't I clear ? Please if not tell me than I will try to improve my question.

Comment: Explanation why to use %I instead of %s [Postgre FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

Comment: I'm already doing something like this `REPLACE(p.nom_produto, 'S B', 'S_B')` in my query, and I'll have to do more so. This is why I'm doing this dict replacement thing. If you do have suggestion for multiple replaces I would be glad to hear.